# Does BB-8 actually have an escape mode?

Tags: star-wars, bb-8

I have this licensed T-shirt:

[image]

One of the blueprints here shows a sphere mode of BB-8 called "escape mode".

[image]

The same detail is used on a variety of BB-8 licensed shirts.

I know he doesn't use it in the movie. However, do we ever see this mode mentioned anywhere else? Blu-Ray extras? The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary? The Art of The Force Awakens? Anything?

Or, even a mention about how the early concept was changed to not have in. I've seen several early BB-8 designs, but I never thought to look for this.

Answer (score 5):

### Probably not

The only other picture I can find comes from [this website](http://lestoilesheroiques.fr/2015/09/star-wars-le-reveil-de-la-force-une-nouvelle-date-de-sortie-francaise.html), which has a BB-8 schematic showing its escape mode:

[image]

However, the schematic here appears identical to that on the shirt, and the source is uncertain.

**More relevant, though, is this: If this is BB-8's "escape" mode, why does the droid not use it during *The Force Awakens* when it needs to, well, escape?**

[image]

This, I think, renders the possibility that this is BB-8's escape mode somewhat unlikely. Note that the T-shirt appeared [significantly in advance of the movie](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/08/bb-8s-escape-mode-from-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-revealed/), and thus BB-8's actions in the movie were still uncertain.

Comment: That's a fan site and the same images as on the T-shirts. I don't know if it was based on early marketing concepts, or if BB is meant to have it in his final design.

Comment: Wasn't me. It happens.

Comment: "Work in progress" answers are frowned upon. You shouldn't hit the Post button if you're not ready typing. Note I didn't downvote, but I would if I saw answers that basically said "Stand by..."

Comment: Wasn't the MacGuffin in BB-8's body? That would explain why she never used a theoretical escape mode (and she was keeping up just fine). Out-of-universe, much of BB-8 and R2-D2's charm is being small and a bit awkward and seeing how they deal with that. If she had the ability to fly that would take away from that charm like R2-D2's reviled flying scenes from the prequels.